# AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection' with managed `Queue`

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following utility functions to isolate a function to its own process.

```py
def safeRunWrapper(func, q, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        result = None
    q.put(result)

def safeRun(func, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Runs a function in its own process
    """
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        q = manager.Queue()
        p = mp.Process(target=safeRunWrapper, args=(func, q, *args), kwargs=kwargs)
        p.start()
        p.join()
        return q.get()
```

Example usage :

```py
def f(a, b):
    return a + b
r = safeRun(f, 1, 2) # r == 3
```

But it occasionally throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 814, in _callmethod
    conn = self._tls.connection
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/path/to/my/file.py", line 219, in safeRunWrapper
    q.put(result)
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 818, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 805, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 501, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 629, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've read the few articles about this error and they all seem to be linked to the child process running ahead of the main process but I don't think that's the case here since I'm calling `p.join()` and `q.get()` which are both blocking functions.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The traceback looks incomplete at the end.